# How to check an already existing record in Magento?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I am trying to perform an SQL query kind of thing where I need to check if my database table contains a particular record or not. If it does, do nothing else add the record which isn't present.

My table sample contains fields like `sample_id (auto-incremented), order_id, order_email_id, review_request, coupon_sent`. It has got 4 records having `order_ids (71, 74, 126, 165)`

To obtain $ids, I have this query,

```
$to_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('-3 days'));
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status', 'complete')->addFieldToFilter('updated_at',array('to' => $to_date ))->addAttributeToSelect('customer_email')->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id');
foreach($orders as $order)
{
  $email = $order->getCustomerEmail();
  $id = $order->getEntityId();
  $sample = Mage::getModel('sample/sample')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $id)->addFieldToSelect('order_id');
  if($sample != null)
  {echo "Record already exists";}
  else
  { 
     echo "Insert this record";
     $sample->setOrderId($id);
  } 
}
```

My `$id` contains `(71, 74, 126, 165, 166, 167)`

So ideally the below query should check against existing records `(71, 74, 126, 165)` and insert new ones `(166, 167)`. I echoed the query and it returned right but it still echoed 'Record already exists' for ids 166 and 167 which ideally it shouldn't

Is there any other way to check the value of an existing field in the table in Magento?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why the `" "`, does Magento make an automagical space? What is actually in `$sample` at that time?

Comment: $sample contains the values for 'order_id' field from 'sample' table according to my query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done in a few steps using [collection filtering](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections).

```
$wantedIds = $orders->getAllIds();
$sample = Mage::getModel('sample/sample')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('order_id', array('in' => $wantedIds)
    ->addFieldToSelect('order_id');
$presentIds = $sample->getColumnValues('order_id');
$newIds = array_diff($wantedIds, $presentIds);
```

The final step gives you the IDs that still need to be created. It is easy to use them since they are an array.

```
foreach ($newIds as $id) {
    Mage::getModel('sample/sample')
        ->setOrderId($id)
        ->save();
}
```

Comment: Well I should have mentioned the fact that my $id is coming from yet another query and hence I am not sure if this can be passed as an array the way you have mentioned or not. I have edited the question though.

Comment: Answer adjusted to start from a collection.

Comment: Great! It worked. Is there a similar function [like getAllIds()] to retrieve all the email Ids for the corresponding order ids as well? Because I need to store both order id and is respective email id in my 'sample' table. But thanks for your modified answer.

Comment: Use the same [`getColumnValues()`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Data/Varien_Data_Collection.html#getColumnValues) method that is used for getting order IDs.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly fine! But just a question for my reference, so henceforth, If I need to check a particular field's value against any given value, there is no direct method like hasData() or has*() to check for the value of existing record? But Thanks anyway. Your input is always valuable.

Comment: There is [`getItemsByColumnValue`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Data/Varien_Data_Collection.html#getItemsByColumnValue) but that only works on loaded collections, meaning the entire table is read into memory. Setting a filter uses the database's indexes which is much faster, but then the matched models are constructed which still uses a bit of PHP memory. The most refined way would be to execute some `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE order_id IN (...)` query directly, that doesn't exist in collections so you would have to write it yourself from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I thought its not advisable to use raw SQL queries, is it? Like I was also trying to prepare a query which could find me the piece of code that For ex: gives me the email id of the review submitted by a non registered customer. But since I thought we cannot use direct SQL queries, I tried looking up for some other methods which could get the email ids.

Comment: It is not advised because using collections is often quicker and more reliable, and takes care of some common security problems like escaping user supplied values. At some point an SQL query is going to be executed somewhere and if collections don't support what you are trying to do then you must do it yourself. But I made a mistake, collections do have one way of retrieving a count and that is with [`getSize()`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Data/Varien_Data_Collection_Db.html#getSize) - it queries the database directly and saves the effort of loading all matching models.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6755/discussion-between-ivn-and-clockworkgeek)

Answer (score 1):

In order to check whether the value/condition exists or not in custom table, try as:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('custom-module/entity-model')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('field-to-check', $value_to_check)->getFirstItem();
if($collection->getId()){
    //such condition/value exists
}else{
   //such condition/value doesn't exist
}
```

Just a concept.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your replies, but I have already tried your method and the answer suggested by @clockworkgeek is what i was looking for. But thanks for your help and interest too. Appreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

Connect magento database :

```
$conn = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read'); 

// perform sql queries
$result = $conn->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM sample;");
foreach($result as $rows) {
   echo $rows['order_ids'] . "\n";
}
```

So, you can use a simple SQL expression with this way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Even I have prepared a SQL query using the Magento way and its correct. But using the result set of that query, I dont know how do I check the value of an existing field in another table with the value I have obtained from my query.

Comment: I don't know, have you used SQL JOIN technique? For instance, SQL IN operator should check values where available in the target table/field. You can do by single query which is returning value will be unique rows. As a result, yo will have only rows that available in both table.

Comment: @ivn I doubt about `null`, are you sure returning value equal to `null`? Try to echo `$sample` and let us the result pls.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, but the answer suggested by @clockworkgeek is what i was looking for. But thanks for your help and interest too. Appreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

since using model is deprecated we use this to load with specific field and save data.

we need these 4 classes to load and update or add new data

```
1. `\vendor\module\Model\testFactory $ModeltestFactor`
2. `\vendor\module\Model\ResourceModel\test $ResourceModelytest
3.`\vendor\module\Model\testRepository $ModelRepositorytest`
4.`\vendor\module\Api\Data\testInterfaceFactory $InterfaceFactorytest`
```

and in class

```
  $model = $this->ModeltestFactor->create();
  $this->ResourceModeltest->load($model,'123456','column_name');

  if ($model->getData()){
      $model->setBinTo('Bin_Code');
  }else {
      $model = $this->InterfaceFactorytest->create();
      $model->setNumber('No');
      $model->setMoveBy('jjjjj');
      $model->setItem('Item_No');
  }

  $this->ModelRepositorytest->save($model);
```

**EDIT**
or you can use only two classes

```
1. `\vendor\module\Model\testFactory $ModeltestFactor`
2. `\vendor\module\Model\ResourceModel\test $ResourceModelytest
```

and in class

```
  $model = $this->ModeltestFactor->create();
  $this->ResourceModeltest->load($model,'123456','column_name');

  if ($model->getData()){
      $model->setBinTo('Bin_Code');
  }else {
      $model->setNumber('No');
      $model->setMoveBy('jjjjj');
      $model->setItem('Item_No');
  }

  $this->ModelRepositorytest->save($model);
```